# Do we really need Google services to increase profits?

Tags: seo, google, google-adsense, ecommerce

Do we really need Google services like analytics (maybe), Adwords, remarketing etc. to increase profits?

I ask this question because according to my observation e-commerce sites pay huge amount of money to Google for ads.  Google acts like business partner and gets it's share.   The advice that I have seen is that if you want to sustain your e-commerce existence, you should pay Google (like a mob boss).

Comment: Many Google services such as Google Search, Google Analytics, Google Search Console, and Google Trends are free.    If those free services help you improve your website, I don't see a reason that you shouldn't use those.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller You are right they are helpful and free, but think Google is a Country, to live, in that country you have to pay some taxes (to put in a simple way), Google does the same in internet if you want your e-commerce site exist you have to pay for it in return you get ads to gain traffic, i have tested this if you stop using google ads profits decrease in the same day.

Answer (score 1):

The profitablility of a site is not directly related to the purchase of Google services like Analytics, AdWords, remarketing, etc. These are value added services which can assist in the marketing of a website. You ask do you really need these services to rise profits, well strictly speaking you don't. Any e-commerce site should be theoretically capable of sustaining itself and producing some description of profit of the sale of goods. What you need to remember is the purpose of the various Google services you cite. Google Analytics is good as it provides you with information on your website visitors and what pages they visit, which in an e-commerce site can indicate how many visitors wind up purchasing something, and what products are looked at the most even if they are not purchased in the end, along with a whole slew of other metrics which can be of great use to improving your site and product range to attract more business. AdWords is the online equivalent of putting a billboard up in a public space, and serves as an advertisement to encourage potential customers to come to your site.

Are they necessary, no. Are they a good idea and are they worth it, most definitively.

NB: Analytics is a free service so the question arises why you wouldn't use it given that it provides so many benefits and doesn't cost anything to use.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge, you are right in many aspects, but the thing is if you can not cooperate with google which %99 of searches are made in, your web site doesnt get any traffic or get very less traffic, so you will say google rules the internet, if all searches are made in google, you should pay for it, you are right but at this point we can not say all the searches and relevancy is organic,  so question is arise here, how do we recieve more traffic without using google services, why we are depend on google?. By the way Analytics Pro is pricey so is adwrods.

Comment: You need to remember that having Analytics and AdWorse or other such services is not a requirement to ranking in Google. Google ranking is done independently of what Google services a site may or may not use and is based on a large number of signals which mainly deal with the content of the site in question. Using AdWords will enable marketing of your site through the AdSense program, and using Analytics (free or pro) will enable you to access key metrics to improve your site, but you don't have to use these services in order to rank in Google. As with most things Google content is king.

Comment: I agree with you, you are totaly right for those who doesnt run e-commerce web site, to get traffice from google users, we advertise on words to show our self in relevant area when words are searched, and if someone or your opponents paid for it you have to pay more etc., to attract people to gain more traffic you have to do it, and for remarketing services if a product is searched and if you want to be listed on top, again you have to deal with google etc. you are very right we do not have to use google services but how we are going to attract people, what are the other ways of gain traffic +

Comment: + to turn them from potential customer to real customer.

Comment: @ChrisRutherfurd *AdWorse* Seems Freudian to me. ;-) Cheers!!